# Struct vs class implementing an interface

Tags: c#

```
private static void TestStructInterface()
{
    IFoo foo1 = new FooClass(); // works
    IFoo foo2 = new FooStruct(); // works
    IEnumerable<IFoo> foos1 = new List<FooClass>(); // works
    IEnumerable<IFoo> foos2 = new List<FooStruct>(); // compiler error
}

interface IFoo
{
    string Thing { get; set; }
}

class FooClass : IFoo
{
    public string Thing { get; set; }
}

struct FooStruct : IFoo
{
    public string Thing { get; set; }
}
```

The compiler complains:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Tests.Program.FooStruct>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Tests.Program.IFoo>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why?
Why is there a difference between classes and structs?
Any workarounds?

Comment: See SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net
And accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13275/1155847

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688268/why-cannot-ienumerablestruct-be-cast-as-ienumerableobject

Comment: Just a minor thing about terminology: interfaces are `implemented`, not `inherited`.

Comment: Thanks @Chips_100, headline corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Bharathram Attiyannan answered, variance is simply not supported for value types.

The workaround is simple:

```
List<FooStruct> listOfFooStruct = new List<FooStruct>();
IEnumerable<IFoo> enumerableOfFoo = listOfFooStruct.Cast<IFoo>();
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been already answered here - [Why covariance and contravariance do not support value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12454794/442444) , but summarizing it for easier look up.

The behavior you are trying to implement is called Variance.

This is due to a restriction enforced in CLR which is explained in [Eric Lippert's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) -

> Covariant and Contravariant conversions of interface and delegate
>   types require that all varying type arguments be of reference types

The reason is explained in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx#InterfaceCovariantTypeParameters):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type
>   for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the
>   resulting constructed type.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Do you have a suggestion for a workaround?

Comment: Sorry could not workout the exact solution for you.. But from what I understand you need to explicitly type cast Struct to Class. This answer might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9688362/442444