# Can not cast my Matrix type to IEnumerable<IEnumerable<float>>

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a Matrix class which has this signature:

```
public partial struct Matrix : IEnumerable<Vector>, IEquatable<Matrix> { ... }
```

Then, similarly, I have a Vector class as so:

```
public partial struct Vector : IEnumerable<float>, IEquatable<Vector> { ... }
```

So, somewhere else in the code, I have:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<float>> floatEnumerationEnumeration = matrix;
```

But it fails to compile, saying it cannot convert a `Matrix` to an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<float>>`.

But I can't see why not?

Comment: I think it's a similar issue that is covered http://stackoverflow.com/a/9688362

Answer (score 1):

`Matrix` implements `IEnumerable<Vector>` but not `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<float>>`. Either let it implement `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<float>>` as well or cast it to the right type:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<float>> floatEnumerationEnumeration =
    matrix.Cast<IEnumerable<float>>();
```

Note that if `B` derives from `A` then this does not mean that `T<B>` also derives from `T<A>`. In fact `T<A>` and `T<B>` are considered to be two distinct unrelated types.

It is not easy to see why, but let's take another example:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Student : Person
{
    public char Grade { get; set; } 
}
```

Now let's assume that this was allowed:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

List<Person> persons = students;
persons.Add(new Person()); // Oops!
```

The the underlying list is still a students list and it does not allow you to add objects of type `Person`!

Okay your example is different and it should work if you know how the types are implemented. But C# sees only abstract syntax constructs and does know what the types are really intended to do. The compiler is not able to say: *"Okay `IEnumerable<T>` does not have an `Add` method, therefore this problem will not occur"*. Therefore generic types cannot automatically be co- or contravariant.