# Mapping List`1 to Object properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mapping

I have a structure defined

```
public class FullIndexList
{
    public IList<IndexCurrency> IndexCurrency { get; set; }

    public IList<Indices> Indices { get; set; }
 }
```

[The List returned from the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xYqX.jpg)

So basically the list items are properties FullIndexList ,the type is List`1

I want to convert the result to FullIndexList.

I have tried using cast as results.Cast() it givens error as invalid cast, I have also  tried using results.ConvertAll
but in that case I need to hard code like this

```
fullIndexList.IndexCurrency = results[0] as IList<IndexCurrency>;
fullIndexList.Indices = results[1] as IList<Indices>;
```

which does not looks right.

I can think of using Reflection or Automapper but I believe there might be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Use conversion operator.

Comment: Try : fullIndexList.IndexCurrency.AddRange(results[0].Select(x => (IndexCurrency)x).ToList());

Comment: I do not want to hard code indexes of result else fullIndexList.IndexCurrency = results[0] as IList<IndexCurrency>;  is more friendly

Comment: @vivek can you please provide a sample code

Comment: *The List returned from the method* What is the type of "the list" and what is "the method"? Why don't you create `FullIndexList` objects right away in "the method"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it done using zip and tupple.

```
foreach (var tuple in typeof(FullIndexList).GetProperties().Zip(results, Tuple.Create))
{
   tuple.Item1.SetValue(full, tuple.Item2, null);
}
```

where FullIndexList is the container type.

However I am not performing any check and assuming the order and no of items in both list are exactly same.

Answer (score 0):

This makes your result flat and then find the type to make `IList`.

```
var flat = results.OfType<IEnumerable<object>>().SelectMany((x) => x).ToArray();
fullIndexList.IndexCurrency = flat.OfType<IndexCurrency>().ToList();
fullIndexList.Indices = flat.OfType<Indices>().ToList();
```

Your `results` is `List<dynamic>` so need to cast it to `IEnumerable<object>` or any other common base class or interface. This means if your `IndexCurrency` or `Indices` is struct, it's difficult. Struct cannot be casted directly to `object`. [Why cannot IEnumerable<struct> be cast as IEnumerable<object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688268/why-cannot-ienumerablestruct-be-cast-as-ienumerableobject)

If you can make `results` not to use `dynamic`, it becomes very easy because you can directly make it flat by `SelectMany()`.

Comment: Error 26 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Rahul What is the type of `results`, `results[0]` and `results[1]`? I assumed they are `List<List<object>>` and `List<object>` type.

Comment: result is List`1 and results[0] List<IndexCurrency> , results[1] List<Indices>

Comment: @Rahul Oh you mean `results` is `List<dynamic>` type. `IndexCurrency` and `Indices` are class or struct?