# Creating a joined string from an object that refers to an array of structs or classes

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

How to correctly get `String.Join` to handle an array when it is referred by `object` likely with some casting to `IEnumerable`?

```
object myArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", myArray)); // prints System.Int32[]
```

Particular context:

I have a view in which I receive a list of properties via reflection. These can be single items as well as collections. I wish to print them (the single value or a joined string).

How can I convert a collection to a joined string? I tried (among other things) the following, but this does not work:

```
@foreach (PropertyInfo cell in Model.GetData().ToList())
{
    <td>
    @{ object value = cell.GetValue(row, null);}
    @(cell.IsCollection() ?
        String.Join(", ", (value as IEnumerable<object>)
            .Select(o => o.ToString()).Select(o => o.ToString())) : value)
    </td>
 }
```

Info:

- Cells' type is PropertyInfo.
- Value is either an object or an object[]. The object or items in the object array can be a string, a boolean or a integer
- `IsCollection` is a self written (and tested) extension method which returns true when the PropertyInfo Cell contains a Collection as value

UPDATE:
The following does not work either:

```
if (cell.IsCollection())
{
     values = String.Join(", ", (IEnumerable<object>)value);                              
}
```

This gives the following error:

> Can't convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]` to type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.Object]`.'

Note that:

```
IEnumerable<object>)value
```

This works.

```
String.Join(", ", (IEnumerable<object>)value)
```

Throws an error of type System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Does anyone know how I can do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply:

```
var joinedString = String.Join(", ", value as IEnumerable<object>);
```

And this:

```
.Select(o => o.ToString()).Select(o => o.ToString())
```

is wrong. Because:

```
// cast to `IEnumerable` of type `object`
(value as IEnumerable<object>)  

// convert to IEnumerable<string>
.Select(o => o.ToString())

// join everything to one string
String.Join(", ", ...)

// and then you again call select on `string`
// which operates on IEnumerable<char>
.Select(o => o.ToString()))
```

So as you see, you need to remove these two `Select` calls.

**UPDATE:**

Oh, I see. You cannot cast `IEnumerable<struct>` to `IEnumerable<object>` due to language restrictions.

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688268/why-cannot-ienumerablestruct-be-cast-as-ienumerableobject)

Try this:

```
// you need to cast to non-generic `IEnumerable`
// then use `Cast` extension method to convert to generic enumerable
IEnumerable<object> valueAsEnumerable = ((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>();

// then use it in `string.join`
var joinedString = String.Join(", ", valueAsEnumerable);
```