# Boxing a list of structs

Tags: c#, .net-core, boxing

I'm trying to box values to an IEnumerable for a JsonConverter to be able to loop through dynamic data.  However, I'm running into problems when trying to box a list of DateTime, or other structs.

```
        var datetime = DateTime.Now ;
        var boxed = datetime as object;  // Works: boxed is still a DateTime value

        var datetimeList = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now };
        var boxedEnumerable = datetimeList as IEnumerable<object>; // Does not work, boxedEnumerable is null
```

Casting to an IEnumerable seems to work well for all reference types, but not value types.

**Note:** The non-generic IEnumerable class can be used for these types of conversions instead of IEnumerable.

Comment: I am curious why you need to box them in the first place?

Comment: We are using reflection on the class for a custom JsonConverter.  So for any list types, we want to handle them differently..

Comment: Have you tried the linq method Cast? 
datetimeList.Cast<object>()

Comment: In our real example, we wouldn't know we'd have an IEnumerable to begin with, so Linq methods won't work.  We only have an object type when we use Property.GetValue() from the reflection.

Comment: .Cast<object> is doing foreach within, casting each record in the enumerable to <type> in your case object. Maybe you can try to do the same? Or simply create list of objects and add (object) DateTime.Now to it?

Comment: So, the property value is boxed already so we only have an object type, because we're using reflection.  So we try to convert that object  to an IEnumerable to see if it's a list type.  So unfortunately, if we can't get it from an object to an IEnumerable, I don't see how we can iterate through it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688268/why-cannot-ienumerablestruct-be-cast-as-ienumerableobject

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy, that seems to highlight the problem, unfortunately the solution of using cast doesn't work for our use case since we only have an object type to begin with when using GetValue() from reflection.

Comment: Can you cast to non-generic System.Collections.IEnumerable?

Comment: Thank you.  I really should have thought of that.  Non-generic IEnumerable works, then I can evaluate each item separately.

Answer (score 0):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type
>   for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the
>   resulting constructed type

More details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance?redirectedfrom=MSDN#InterfaceCovariantTypeParameters